# How do I run MP2 and/or CCSD-level hyperpolarizability calculations with GAMESS?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, optical-properties

I have used GAMESS before for TDHF (RPA) / TDDFT level first hyperpolarizability ($\beta$) calculations. However, I cannot figure out how to calculate $\beta$ with MP2 and CCSD for comparative purposes. Do I have to use the `FFIELD` keyword for the finite field approach? If that is the case, what is the general workflow necessary to calculate the time-varying hyperpolarizability?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. Please feel free to take a [tour] of this site to get a brief idea of who we are, and what topics are suitable here. Good luck, and hope to see you satisfied soon.

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, to calculate $\beta$ within GAMESS for MP2 and CCSD, you would need to perform first- and second-order finite difference, respectively, as there is no coupled cluster gradient needed, so no true CCSD dipole moment.

However, there is a more fundamental problem: it is impossible to calculate time-dependent response using a finite field approach. Take the general form of [1-dimensional 2nd-order central difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences),
$$
f''(x) \approx \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2},
$$

which can directly translate to a diagonal element of the polarizability tensor formed from energies at finite electric fields:

$$
\alpha_{zz}(x) \approx \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{E(x+h)-2E(x)+E(x-h)}{h^2}
$$

where $h$ is a finite electric dipole field of some strength applied along the $z$-direction. What is $x$? Is it as simple as converting the desired frequency $\omega$ to units of electric field strength? No; that still corresponds to a static field rather than a time-varying field. How are the different perturbation directions handled? $x$ must be set to 0.

From a [molecular properties review by Jurgen Gauss](http://webarchiv.fz-juelich.de/nic-series//Volume3/gauss.pdf), page 5:

> (...) disadvantages of the numerical differentiation scheme are
>
> a) that there is no straightforward extension to the computation of frequency-dependent properties (...)

Page 37:

> While analytic derivative theory is sufficient for the theoretical treatment of time-independent (static) properties, the underlying theory needs to be extended for the calculation of time-dependent (dynamical) properties. In particular, the fact that there is -- unlike for the static case -- in the time-dependent case no well-defined energy explains why the simple derivative theory discussed so far is not applicable.

Page 39 (with some manipulation by me):

> It can be shown that the linear, quadratic, etc. response functions $\left<\left<A;B\right>\right>_{w_{b}}$, $\left<\left<A;B,C\right>\right>_{w_{b},w_{c}}$, etc. and thus the frequency-dependent properties of interest can be determined as derivatives of the so-called time-averaged quasi energy
>
> $$
> Q(t) = \left<\tilde{\psi}\left|\left(H - i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\right|\tilde{\psi}\right>
> $$
>
> with the phase-isolated wavefunction
>
> $$
> \tilde{\psi}(t) = e^{iF(t)} \psi(t)
> $$

where $F$ is a time-varying external field, and $\psi(t)$ is the usual wavefunction where MO coefficients and thus the density are explicitly time-dependent.

The only numerical (rather than analytic) method for calculating dynamic properties I am aware of is direct time-propagation of the wavefunction. If you want to calculate frequency-dependent CCSD hyperpolarizabilities, your best (free) bet is [DALTON](http://daltonprogram.org/www/features.html). Note that their coupled cluster module is closed-shell only.

Comment: Thank you for your response; it was very informative and I am grateful for the resource you have provided.  I believe analytic gradients for CCSD and MP2 for the first hyperpolarizability have previously been published, is it just the case  that they have not been implemented into GAMESS?  Or am I mistaken about their derivation?

Comment: The point is that they are not implemented in GAMESS. Analytic gradients for MP2 and CCSD are in most packages. Very few programs (DALTON, Gaussian) can calculate correlated hyperpolarizabilities.

Comment: @ComputationalNovice If my answer was useful, please consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: NWChem has had CCSD quadratic response hyperpolarizabilities with non-zero frequencies since 2008.  You can do RHF, UHF or ROHF, but I strongly recommend ROHF for open shells, for reasons discussed in the paper linked last.
https://nwchemgit.github.io/TCE.html#input
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/130/19/194108/296267/Parallel-computation-of-coupled-cluster
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/128/22/224102/924805/Coupled-cluster-dynamic-polarizabilities-including

Comment: https://github.com/nwchemgit/nwchem/tree/45332c485cdc3143c13b382848b3acdbd967f4f3/QA/tests/tce_hyperpolar_ccsd_small is an example input file, since it seems the user manual is not complete (my fault)